# get name roll in SimpleMemberShip

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I make one application in MVC 4, with SimpleMemberShip, with four roles:

Administrator

> Consultant
>   Standard
>   New

I need get the name role of profile of user Log in, for to to give the appropriate functions.

I tried this:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
     {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admnistrador"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Administrador", "Usuario");

        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Nuevo"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Nuevo", "Usuario");
        }
    }
}
```

and other this it

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
        var perfil = from u in _DB.usuario
                     where u.UserName == "marios"
                     select u.perfil;


     if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
     {
        if (perfil.Equals("Admnistrador"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuario");
        }

        if (perfil.Equals("Nuevo"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Usuario");
        }
     }
 }
```

But not results or views.

Answer (score 0):

I auto reply me.

I find this this POST.

[Implement secure ASP.NET MVC applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288631/Secure-ASP-NET-MVC-applications)

Now,  my new code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl )
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe) )
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Administrador"))
               {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuario"); 
               }

            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Nuevo"))
               { 
                return RedirectToAction("About", "Home"); 
               }

        }

        // Si llegamos a este punto, es que se ha producido un error y volvemos a mostrar el formulario

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "El nombre de usuario o la contraseña especificados son incorrectos.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

With this code custom my own views from contollers.

Regards

thanks for your patience.